# Flash Builder 4.7 and Inspectable metadata tag

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

Since I migrated to FB 4.7 premium, I don't see code hints for my components' attributes anymore.

For instance, the inspection of this attribute used to work:

```
[Inspectable(category="Common",enumeration="normal,small",defaultValue="normal")]
public function set size(size:String):void {
    // code
}
```

Did I miss something with FB 4.7 config?

----- EDITION
@Lee Burrows:

I'm not sure to understand your point: if FB 4.7 ignores Inspectable tag, how is it able to suggest values for SDK attributes?

An example for VGroup.verticalAlign attribute:

```
[Inspectable(category="General", enumeration="top,bottom,middle", defaultValue="top")]
public function get verticalAlign():String
{
    return verticalLayout.verticalAlign;
}
```

In the mxml editor, FB suggests values "top", "bottom" and "middle" for verticalAlign, so why is it not able to suggest my components attributes values as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I made some tests and I found two things that changed with FB 4.7:

- In order to see the hints on the authorized value, the attribute must have a setter AND a getter (some of my components had only a setter, which is bad I agree)
- The [Inspectable] metadata tag should be placed before the getter, and getter only

So the correct syntax for my example is:

```
[Inspectable(category="Common",enumeration="normal,small",defaultValue="normal")]
public function get size():String {
    // code
}

public function set size(size:String):void {
    // code
}
```

Now I see the values as code hint in FB 4.7 again.

Answer (score 0):

FB 4.7 doesnt have a design view - making the [Inspectable] metatag redundant (i believe it was only used by the design view to determine acceptable values for property input fields).

Comment: I think I was not clear: I'm not talking of the design view, but of code hints in the code editor.
The same code hints you see when you type 'verticalAlign' in a VGroup tag, which are 'bottom' 'middle' and 'top'. I used to have the same behavior for my own components with Inspectable tags, but it is not true anymore.

And what do you mean by Inspectable tag redundancy?

Comment: Sorry - i guess i wasnt clear either ;) i meant that Inspectable tag is used internally by Flash Builder design view - and as design view is no longer a part of FB, it ignores Inspectable tag completely (even in code view). By redundant i mean "has no useful purpose" - from FBs point of view, not necessarily yours.